# Typescript can not infer undefined or null checking in function

Tags: typescript

I have an issue with Typescript type checking when I'm using a function. Let say I have a Type `IBaseField` and I have a variable of Type `Array<IBaseField>`. When I want to assign a value to this variable I will check for `null` and `undefined` and I will assign an empty array or a new value based on the function result. But typescript shows an error that Type `IBaseField[] | undefined`  is not assignable to type `IBaseField[]` While I have checked it in the function. Here is the code I have tried:

```
  public constructor(formId:ID, autoFillFields?: Array<IBaseField>) {
    this._formId = formId
    this._autoFillFields = isNullOrUndefined(autoFillFields) ? [] : autoFillFields
  }
```

and here is my `isNullOrUndefined` function:

```
export function isNullOrUndefined(obj: any) {
  return obj === null || obj === undefined
}
```

and the error shown by typescript:

> Type 'IBaseField[] | undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'IBaseField[]'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'IBaseField[]'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell typescript that `isNullOrUndefined` is a type guard:

```
export function isNullOrUndefined(obj: any): obj is null | undefined {
  return obj === null || obj === undefined
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards